# jQuery .after() method inserting a row that is stuffing itself into one cell. Why?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, row

I'm trying to add cells to the right side of this table with jQuery, under the active row when clicked.  I got it down to inserting a row,  which is functioning on click, and toggled with the help of CSS.

For some reason,  the .after() method that is injecting HTML below the active row,  appears to be stuffing all the HTML into the first cell,  instead of injecting it into the table and functioning like a normal row.  I'm not exactly sure why.  I think it may be something to do with my CSS and the solution I fashioned for toggling the row's display, but I may be wrong.  Changing the CSS display mode doesn't fix this.

[image: Here is a picture of the problem]

Any help would be super appreciated!

CSS:

```
      .metadata {
                display: none;
            }

        .metadata.active {
                display: block;
            }
        table {
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
            margin-right:20px;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
        }

        td, th {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        th {
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 15px;

        }
        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #F5F5F5;
        }

    .content:hover {
        background-color: #99d1db;


cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="table" style="text-align:center;">

        <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th >blah</th>
            <th>blah</th>
            <th>blah</th>
            <th>blah</th>
            <th>blah</th>
            <th>blah</th>

        </tr>
        <tr class="content">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="tablebox" value="checker"></td>
            <td>blah</td>
            <td>blah</td>
            <td>blah</td>
            <td>blah</td>
            <td>blah</td>
            <td>blah</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click','table tr', function(){
    var row =  $(this).closest('tr') ;
    if (row.next().hasClass("metadata")) {

        row.next().toggleClass("active");

    }
    else {
        $(row.after('<tr class="content metadata active" ><td>something</td><td>something</td><td>something</td><td>something</td><td>something</td></tr>')); 

    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change `display:none` to `display:block` , so the inserted row will behave like a `block` element not like a `table-row` . You need to set `display:table-row`

Also, add an empty first column to the new row, so it's columns will stay aligned with the above rows

see snippet below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', 'table tr', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    if (row.next().hasClass("metadata")) {

      row.next().toggleClass("active");

    } else {
      $(row.after('<tr class="content metadata active" ><td></td><td>something</td><td>something</td><td>something</td><td>something</td><td>something</td></tr>'));

    }
  });
});
```

```css
.metadata {
  display: none;
}

.metadata.active {
  display: table-row;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

td,
th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

th {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.content:hover {
  background-color: #99d1db;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table" style="text-align:center;">

  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>blah</th>
        <th>blah</th>
        <th>blah</th>
        <th>blah</th>
        <th>blah</th>
        <th>blah</th>

      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="tablebox" value="checker">
        </td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```